# Доступ к экземпляру класса в статичной функции

Tags: c++, lua

Столкнулся с проблемой. Нужно вставить в таблицу, в луа C-функцию, которая должна обращаться к НЕ статичному полу (экземпляру класса).
Пробовал использовать лямбды, но не получается привести их к lua_CFunction.
Как можно это реализовать?

```
class Computer {
        private:
                lua_State *luaState;
        public:
                void run() {
                         luaState = luaL_newstate();
                            lua_createtable(luaState, 0, 1);
        lua_pushcfunction(luaState, /* ?? */);
        lua_setfield(luaState, -2, "test");
                            lua_setglobal(luaState, "computer");
                }
}

Computer *c = new Computer;

c.run();
```

Comment: Самый простой вариант - сделать статическую обёртку. Передавать параметр объект для которого идёт вызов и все должно работать. Кстати функции внутри класса содержат указатель на объект неявно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку вы создаёте `lua_State` внутри вашего объекта, то можно сохранить указатель на объект в таблице, внутри Lua и использовать его для вызова методов. При этом, для каждого метода, который вы хотите вызвать из Lua, вам придётся писать Си-обёртку, которая будет извлекать этот указатель из таблицы и вызывать соответствующий метод.

Например, если вам надо вызвать такой метод:

```
void Computer::test(int i) {
    std::cout << "test: " << i;
}
```

то, вы сохраняете указатель на объект в конструкторе:

```
Computer::Computer(void) {
    luaState = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs( luaState );

    lua_createtable(luaState, 0, 2);

    // указатель на объект
    lua_pushlightuserdata(luaState, this);
    lua_setfield(luaState, -2, "_self");

    // указатель на функцию обёртку
    lua_pushcfunction(luaState, test_wrap);
    lua_setfield(luaState, -2, "test");

    lua_setglobal(luaState, "computer");
}
```

.. и пишите обёртку:

```
int test_wrap(lua_State *L)
{
    // чтение аргумента(ов) функции
    if(!lua_isnumber(L, -1))
        luaL_error(L, "Expected a Number as a first argument!");
    int i = lua_tonumber(L, -1);

    // загрузка указателя
    Computer * pComp = get_obj_pointer(L);

    // вызов метода
    if (pComp) {
        pComp->test(i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Функция чтения указателя на объект из луа-таблицы:

```
Computer * get_obj_pointer(lua_State *L)
{
    lua_getglobal(L, "computer");
    if (!lua_istable(L, -1))
        luaL_error(L, "Table 'computer' is not found!");

    lua_pushstring(L, "_self");
    lua_gettable(L, -2);
    if (!lua_isuserdata(L, -1))
        luaL_error(L, "Value 'computer._self' is not found!");

    void *p = lua_touserdata(L, -1);
    lua_pop(L, 1);

    return (Computer *) p;
}
```

Далее, пишите тестовый скрипт `script.lua`:

```
local comp = computer    
print(comp._self) # напечатает "userdata 0xXXXXXX"
print(comp.test(15)) # напечатает "test: 15"
```

и вызываете его в методе `run`:

```
void Computer::run(void) {
    int err = luaL_dofile(luaState, "script.lua");
    if (err) {
       std::cout << "Error: " << lua_tostring(luaState, -1);
       lua_pop(luaState, 1);
    }
}
```

Тестовый код целиком: https://pastebin.com/FSdsRaAd